# Alamofire multipart image upload gives ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8) on rails server

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to upload an image using Alamofire 4.0. I've established that the server endpoint works with a successful curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;" -F "img=@/path/to/img.jpeg" "http//example.org"
```

But the following code doesn't work:

```
let imageData: Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)!
Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "img", mimeType: "image/jpg")
    },
    to: "http://example.org/",
    headers: [
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    ],
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
            case .success:
                print("SUCCESS")
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
        }
    }
)
```

Due to this error on the server:

```
ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)
```

It seems to be a client side issue, but nothing that I've tried has worked so far.

Comment: I've gotten the upload to work by encoding to a base64 String on the client, and decoding it on the server.

`let imageString64 = "data:image/png;base64,\(imageData.base64EncodedString())"`

I'd still love to get this multipart approach to work though, since that way the server doesn't have to decode each image.